# vbscript to find two row data in notepad

Tags: vb.net

Currently im looking VBS script for find two data in two row. for example: 
Data in Notepad:

```
type 3
logo_0 1
user_data 03_P_120243685
end
ITEM
preset_date 11/08/14
in_src 966000
out_src 966750
mode 0
no_vision_trans 1
type 3
logo_0 1
no_audio_trans 1
type 1
logo_0 2
user_data 03_I_99710581
aspect_ratio 2
type 3
logo_0 1
channel_id 2
use_subtitle 0
type 3
logo_0 1
aspect_ratio 2
channel_id 2
```

A data is : `type 3`
B data is : `LOGO_0 1`

the script need to find this both data and msgbox "Both data are found in notepad" if the second data is not match with `logo_0 1` then msgbox "second data is not found"

the search condition must be find the first data and the second line must be the second data.

In my notepad the a and b data will be continuously repeat. So the script need be to identified if there is condition not match. i hope the given information able to come out any idea from you all.

My current script only able detect the first data.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text) 
    Dim aString As String = "type 1" 
    Dim bString As String = "logo_0 1" 

    If Findstring.Contains(bString) Then MsgBox("Found: " & bString) Else MsgBox("Not found") 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code from your current script and point out the area where you're having trouble.

Comment: Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

        Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText(TextBox1.Text)
        Dim aString As String = "type 1"
        Dim bString As String = "logo_0 1"

        If Findstring.Contains(bString) Then
            MsgBox("Found: " & bString)
        Else
            MsgBox("Not found")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Im using aString as Type 1 and bString is logo_0 1. the Findstring cant find both string with condition.

Comment: This looks like VB.NET. Are you looking for a VBScript solution or a VB.NET one?

Comment: current im testing on the VB.NET. Im need a VBNET solution. Is there any VBscript available for above condition?IF yes Please help to share with me.